# How can I run parent method?

Tags: java, polymorphism

Suppose I have the following classes

```
  Class Parent{
    public void test(){
        System.out.println("Parent");
    }
  }

  Class Child extends Parent{
    public void test(){
        System.out.println("Child");
    }
  }

Parent parentE = new Child();
parentE.test();
((Parent)parentE).test();
```

Output is:

```
Child
Child
```

But how can I run parent method in this case using parentE reference?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21613540/casting-to-superclass-and-calling-overriden-method

Comment: use this Parent parentE = new Parent();

Comment: Could you explain why you want to do this? There may be a better way or overriding may simply be inappropriate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a key feature of polymorphism.

The object you instantiated is an instance of `Child`. Calling that object's `test()` is *always* going to result in the `Child`'s (overridden) `test()` being called, even if you've assigned that instance to a variable of `Parent` type.

In short, this is how you can achieve more specific behavior while only having to reference the object using a variable declared a superclass type. Often this is used in conjunction with the base class only providing an abstract method for the subclasses to override.

A trivial example in beginner's books usually involves animals or cars:

```
public abstract class Animal
{
    private final String name;

    public Animal(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void printName()
    {
        System.out.println(name);
    }

    // more animal general stuff followed by:

    public abstract void makeSound();

}

public class Dog extends Animal
{
    public Dog()
    {
        super("Dog");
    }

    @Override
    public void makeSound()
    {
        System.out.println("Woof!");
    }
}

List<Animal> aList = new ArrayList<Animal>();
aList.add(new Dog());
aList.add(new Cat());
// etc
for (Animal a : aList) 
{
    a.printName();
    a.makeSound(); // calls each subclasses' "makeSound()"
}
```

You can't call the `Parent`'s `test()` unless you instantiate a `Parent` or call `super.test()` from within a method in `Child`.

(I was actually thinking I could find a good duplicate for this that provided a decent answer, but I couldn't)

Comment: yes, I was trying to look for a duplicate too, since I thought I just saw the same question a few months ago with a good answer.  Maybe it got deleted.  But I did find an older answer of Jon Skeet's that I linked.

Answer (score 2):

When you [override](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html) the `parent` method, the `child` object will always call the overriding method (`child` method) due to [Polymorphism](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html).

So in your case either you call the `parent` method explicitly, inside the `child` object:

```
Class Child extends Parent{
    public void test(){
        super.test();
    }
  }
```

Or make a Parent object and call it's method.

```
Parent parentE = new Parent();
parentE.test();
```

Comment: I don't think that's what he was asking.

Answer (score 0):

Simple

```
Parent parentE = new Parent();
 parentE.test();
```

Comment: I don't think that's what he was asking.

Answer (score 0):

> In case of `method overriding` that is resolved at `run-time` based on `actual data type of object` not on the basis of referee data type.

You can't call call super class's overridden method directly.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, no, you can't do this, and it would be a bad idea.  If `Child` decides that it needs to override one of its inherited methods, then the outside program shouldn't try to subvert that.  It's as though the author of the outside module peeked into the implementation of the methods in `Parent` and `Child` and decided "I want the Parent version, not the Child version".  But that isn't what OOP is all about.  The writer of the outside program should not be concerned with how the method is implemented.  See [Jon Skeet's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032847/can-java-call-parent-overridden-method-in-other-objects-but-not-subtype), which I think explains this as well as anything I've found.

If you find that you really need to do this, then you have a design issue.  The solution is going to depend on your particular project (your original code isn't a real-world example so there's no way to answer it for that).  But in some cases, the solution *might* be that the classes need to provide *two* different methods that have similar but slightly different purposes.  And it may be that in some subclasses of your class, the two methods would have the exact same implementation, but in other subclasses they would be different.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mixed two concepts over here. `casting` and `polymorphism`. Read about these concept then things will be more clear for you.